# Deleting VSTS User From Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Microsoft Docs has substantive info on *adding* users to VSTS via Active Directory, but I'm not finding specific info on what happens when you delete a VSTS user from AD, or what ripple effects take place when you delete them from VSTS itself. MSFT says removing them from AD *may* make them still appear in VSTS, but they won't be able to log in, yet also says it may take up to 24 hours for *a change* in AD to show up in VSTS.

1. When VSTS is linked to AD, does removing a VSTS user from AD ever remove them from VSTS, or does the user always need to be removed from VSTS manually?
2. Does removing a user directly from within VSTS remove them from any other place in VSTS like "Assigned To" fields, project teams, security groups... anything?

Comment: Regarding first, question, it takes time to verify, will ask you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Are users deleted from AAD when they are deleted from VSTS

No, they are not. AAD is the master list and only when a user is deleted from AAD, are they deleted from other applications, not the other way around. That same user may be present in Office 365 and a long list of other applications or may have been assigned one or more azure resources. As such only from AAD can you completely remove a user.

### When deleting does the user stay visible

The user will remain visible in Work Items, Changesets, Git Commits, Build history, Release history. These records are kept for historical purposes and auditability and they remain.

The active configuration such as security group access, license assignments etc will be dropped in 24h.

Comment: Thank you, jessehouwing. The question #2 answer makes sense and is what I hoped would be the case. Question #1, however, is the inverse of your answer. If a user is deleted from AD, does a background sync process then remove them from VSTS?

Comment: Yes, the sync will remove them from AAD, which will remove them from VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question, the user will be removed from project teams and security groups, but the Assigned to fields won’t be changed even through assigned to this user.